# Get all available permission after NodeType delete - Drupal 8

Tags: 8, entities, hooks

I know that to get all available permissions you can do

```
var_dump(array_keys(\Drupal::service('user.permissions')->getPermissions()));
```

which give you a list of all permissions' name.

I also know that when you create a NodeType, it refresh this list.

So what I want to do here, is to fill a table of my database with a list of all available permissions, that update when permission is add or removed.

When I create a NodeType :

```
function inside_entity_insert(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) : void
{
    if (get_class($entity) === 'Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType') {
        $permissions = array_keys(\Drupal::service('user.permissions')->getPermissions());

        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
        // somestuff -> updating database permission table
        }
     }
}
```

So that means when NodeType is created the Drupal permissions list is updated and I must update my database too.

What I want to do here is the same thing but when a NodeType is deleted.

I tried :

1. hook_entity_delete
2. hook_entity_predelete

But in both hook the ***user.permission*** list didn't change, I still get the same permissions, and what I though is that the permissions of my actual nodetype dissapeared, because of the deletion.

I do not know where to look..

Is getting the name of the nodeType and delete matchings rules' name of the database, a good alternative ?

I also wanted where can I initialize these database, because actually it's created & updated only when someone create a NodeType. But that's not urgent at the moment.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong hooks. I am not sure what your objective is, but you want `hook_ENTITY_BUNDLE_delete` I believe:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_bundle_delete/8.6.x

```
function mymodule_entity_bundle_delete($entity_type_id, $entity) : void
{
    if ($entity_type_id == 'node' && $bundle == 'node type to check') {
        $permissions = array_keys(\Drupal::service('user.permissions')->getPermissions());

        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
        // somestuff -> updating database permission table
        }
     }
}
```

I don't know if you care to check `$bundle` or not, but if you delete any node type, this code should fire.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for. And no, I do not need to check the $bundle, just needed the hook with updated permission that is triggered on nodetype deletion ! So thanks again